# How to automatically load functions into namespace of an R package

Tags: r, namespaces, rstudio, devtools, roxygen2

I have an R package that requires functions from several other packages to be in the namespace. Using roxygen2 documentation, I've successfully *installed* these packages (i.e. `install.packages(dplyr)`), but I am unable to load them in automatically (i.e. `library(dplyr)`).

Here is my DESCRIPTION file:

```
Package: pkgname
Title: What the Package Does (one line, title case)
Version: 0.0.0.9000
Authors@R: person("First", "Last", email = "email@example.com", role = c("aut", "cre"))
Description: What the package does (one paragraph).
Depends: R (>= 3.5.2)
Imports:
  ggplot2,
  zoo,
  tidyr,
  dplyr,
  magrittr
Suggests:
  RColorBrewer
License: What license is it under?
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 6.1.1
```

At the end of the documentation for one of my functions that requires the pipe function from magrittr, I included the following notation:

```
#' @importFrom magrittr %>%
#'
#' @export
funName <- function(...) { 
... 
}
```

And the other function:

```
#' @import ggplot2
#' @importFrom magrittr %>%
#'
#' @export
funName2 <- function(...) {
...
}
```

And this successfully shows up in my NAMESPACE file:

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(funName2)
export(funName)
import(ggplot2)
importFrom(magrittr,"%>%")
```

However, despite the added notation in roxygen2 comments and the correct script in my NAMESPACE file, I still have to load the packages `ggplot2` and `magrittr` using `library(package-name)` at every new R session. I expect this requirement for `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `zoo` (since I do not explicitly load these, just install them), but I did not for `ggplot2` or the `%>%` operator. Am I importing them incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never use `library(package.name)` inside your package functions. Instead use `package.name::function.name()`. 
You need to re-export the `magrittr` pipe operator:

1- put `magrittr` into the DESCRIPTION file (as you did)

2- make an `__imports.R` file to the packages `R/` directory with the following lines:

```
#' re-export magrittr pipe operator
#'
#' @importFrom magrittr %>%
#' @name %>%
#' @rdname pipe
#' @export
NULL
```

Or, similarly do as **Hadley Wickham** [says](https://github.com/sckott/analogsea/issues/32#issue-43772852):

```
#' Pipe operator
#'
#' @name %>%
#' @rdname pipe
#' @keywords internal
#' @export
#' @importFrom magrittr %>%
#' @usage lhs \%>\% rhs
NULL
```

I think you can do the same for other imports when necessary. Use `@importFrom` as much as you can, otherwise re-export it.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I should clarify that I was entering `library(package.name)` into the console, not in the actual function code. Do I need to re-export every function and package I want to use without the `::` operator?

Comment: Oh, thanks. When your package is built all the dependencies are also loaded automatically. exit from your project in RSTUDIO and install it from your github repository in a new console and see whether your package works or not. CMD checking testthat will also do the same for you and if CMD build is successful do not worry. Of course, you need not. `@importFrom` and  `@import` and adding packages names to DESCRIPTION `Imports` are enough. My package [`cvcqv`](https://github.com/MaaniBeigy/cvcqv) is a small package with few dependencies. You may use it as an easy sample. Best wishes.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations, I think you've actually found my problem! I currently haven't uploaded my package, so I've been using `install.packages(package.name, repos=NULL, type="SOURCE")`, and this seems to disable loading in packages. This is why I am required to use `library(x)`. If this is correct, the namespace should load in once I upload it to a repository.

Answer (score 0):

Try and run the following command to get your packages into NAMESPACE

```
devtools::document()
```

After running it, all the imported (@import) packages are gonna be inserted into NAMESPACE.

Hope it helps ;)